# Boolean operators: Branching using Boolean variables ( python)

Tags: python, boolean-operations

I'm working on a homework question and I'm having a terrible time getting it to return the final statement correctly.

Instruction:

> Write an expression that prints 'You must be rich!' if the variables
>   young and famous are both True.

Code (I'm only able to update the if statement):

```
young = True
famous = False
if (young == 'True') and (famous == 'True'):
    print('You must be rich!')
else:
    print('There is always the lottery...')
```

My initial thoughts are the combination in the code above, but I'm desperate and I've tried all the combinations below as well:

```
if (young != 'True') and (famous == 'True'): 
if (young == 'True') and (famous != 'True'): 
if (young == 'True') and (famous != 'False'): 
if (young == 'True') or (famous == 'True'): 
if (young == 'True') or (famous != 'True'): 
if (young == 'True') or (famous == 'True'): 
if (young == 'True') or (famous != 'False'):
```

The results:

Testing with young and famous as both False 
Your output:    There is always the lottery... 
  Testing with young as True and famous as False
Your output:    There is always the lottery... 
  Testing with young as False and famous as True
Your output:    There is always the lottery... 
✖   Testing with young and famous as both True
Expected output:    You must be rich!   
Your output:   There is always the lottery...

Comment: The strings `'True'` and `'False'` are not the same as the boolean values `True` and `False`.

Comment: What khelwood said. You're making this too complicated. Try `if young and famous:`.

Comment: If you want to be strict, so the `if` test passes _only_ if those variables are the booleans `True` you _could_ do `if young is True and famous is True:`, but it's usually better in Python to not be so strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are confused between boolean variables and strings

```
young=True #boolean variable
```

and

```
young='True' #string
```

Here is the corrected code

```
young = True
famous = False
if young and famous:
    print('You must be rich!')
else:
    print('There is always the lottery...')
```

I would recommend you to go through your lessons on strings and boolean variables before using this,Good luck

Comment: Oh, duh! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do note use `''` because `input` already turns the input into strings, AKA `'True'`. If you use `and` and both are true it will be true.

```
young = (input() == 'True')
famous = (input() == 'True')

if (young == True) and (famous == True):
    print('You must be rich!')
else:
    print('There is always the lottery...')
```